# Доброго времени суток,товарищи! У меня возникла какая-то ошибка в python Kivy: Exception: Invalid instance in App.root

Tags: kivy

Да,я только начал эту тему изучать так что не судите строго :D

итак я для теста наклепал самое простое что только можно

main.py:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class Interface():
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Interface()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

myapp.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
<Interface>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:vertical
        Button:
            text:Hello
```

На что интерпретатор выдаёт

```
INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/alex/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-10-19_35.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.1
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34)
[GCC 7.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] App.root must be an _instance_ of Widget
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 13, in <module>
     MyApp().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 806, in run
     raise Exception('Invalid instance in App.root')
 Exception: Invalid instance in App.root
```

Как быть,что делать?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Укажите в Interface нужный лейаут (полагаю, это BoxLayout). `class Interface(BoxLayout)`.
2. Тогда не нужно (избыточно) указывать BoxLayout внутри kv.
3. Исправьте `orientation:'vertical'` и `text:'Hello'` (нужны кавычки)
4. Кнопка не используется в main.py (только в kv) - можно не импортировать

Итого:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class Interface(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Interface()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

myapp.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.1
<Interface>:
    orientation:'vertical'
    Button:
        text:'Hello'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое))

Comment: Если вопрос решен и все работает, вы можете принять ответ (поставить галочку)